# Only 1080p youtube videos work properly

Tags: 12.04, resolution, youtube, fullscreen, hd-video

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit installed/full updated and have noticed that I can only play 1080p youtube videos properly on full screen.  All other resolutions, 480, 720, 1440 etc do not go into full screen properly.  Please have a look at the attached images.  You will notice that only the 1080p video has the video control bar right at the bottom with a respectable text size.  All other videos don't have the video control bar right at the bottom on the screen, and the control bar text is too small.

I've had this problem for ages, but finally decided to ask about it.

**480p:** Notice the bottom control bar, it's not at the bottom on the screen and the video has borders on the sides:
[image: 480p]

**720p:** Notice the bottom control bar, it's not at the bottom on the screen and the video has borders on the sides and the text is tiny:
[image]

**1080p:** This is the only one that works as expected, i.e. controls right at the bottom, and good font size and no borders on the sides:
[image]

**1440p:** Notice the bottom control bar, it's not at the bottom on the screen and the video has borders on the sides:
[image]

How do I correct this problem so I can play all different video resolutions at full screen.

The flash version I have installed in Chromium is Adobe Flash Player - Version: 11.2 r202 - Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you checked it in all the browsers?

Comment: Those screenshots are from Chromium.  I have just tried it in Firefox and I get the same results.

Comment: Does this or similar issues occur on other video sites?
Are you using Flash or HTML5 (https://youtube.com/html5)? If you are using HTML5 try disabling it, if it's disabled try enabling it. If you are using Flash, which plugin do you use (chrome://plugins) and is it the newest version?

Comment: what graphic card are you using?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Both chromium and firefox use older version of flash. Hope that would be the issue. You can get latest version of flash only by installing [Google-Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula). Give it a try.

Comment: The flash version I have installed in Chromium is Adobe Flash Player - Version: 11.2 r202 - Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Comment: @oshirowanen:That is why I told you. You are using some older version of flash. Check the version of flash used by **Browsers** under **Linux** in [Adobe site](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/). Everything will be clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you're using a older version of flash** I hope that would be the problem.

Any browser other than [Google-Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula) doesn't use latest version of flash in Linux. I don't know why Adobe is not releasing latest version of flash for Linux type system, but there is a way to get latest version of flash by using [Google-Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula).

As the main site of [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) says, the latest version of flash player is 11.9.x for OS like Windows and Mac, but for Linux and Solaris, it is version 11.2.x only :(

You can also check the version of flash you are using by opening [adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/). Try to open the site using different browsers. You'll get that while using Chrome, it is different.

It would give information as shown below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1392102_465194326933795_961632591_n.jpg))</sub>

Although I'm not using latest version of **Chrome**.

I can understand your problem and know you pain. But it will not cost any thing if you just give it a try. Who knows that would be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could try the following:
Search for "flash" in Ubuntu Software Centre, and install.
Check which flash plugins are enabled.
Under chrome://plugins/
Check Details Box. Disable .../PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so

Comment: The flash version I have installed in Chromium is Adobe Flash Player - Version: 11.2 r202 - Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason might be that all essential packages are not install/updated. Perhaps the best way to install such non-free but essential packages is to install them using `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. To install this, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Then restart your browser and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was caused by having two screens set to different horizontal positions.

The workaround: go to `System settings` -> `Displays` and drag your screens to align horizontally.

[image]